# Is it okay to say that someone's name is their referent?

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering if the word "referent" is used to say who a name refers to.

For example, in the novel, characters' names tell us much about their referents.

Comment: Got an example of context where you would need this word?

Comment: For example, in the novel, characters' names tell us much about their referents.

Comment: @Mr-Asker Add this example to your question.

Comment: Wouldn’t you just say, “In the novel, a person’s name tells us much about their character.”

Comment: You wouldn't say any of these things. And if you did you'd just sound helpless for not knowing that this is such a common and specific thing in literature that it has a dedicated term, *aptronym*.

Comment: If only you would answer my question instead of offering some alternatives.

Comment: If only you would read my answer: "no, you wouldn't say that". We are offering alternatives because what you have is no good. If it were fine, nobody would say you must use something else instead.

Comment: So, how would you fill the blank in the following sentence? In the novel, characters' names tell us much about their .................... .

Comment: about their personality,  about who they are, about them...

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use the reflexive pronoun himself, herself, itself, etc.

> "His first name is, by itself, quite plain."